# react@experimental 0.0.0 and peer dependencies

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, peer-dependencies

I installed react@experimental which got version `0.0.0-experimental-ee8509801-20230117`. Also I have a library with peer dependency react >=0.14
When I run `npm i` I got following error

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: react-jvectormap@0.0.16
npm ERR! Found: react-dom@0.0.0-experimental-ee8509801-20230117
npm ERR! node_modules/react-dom
npm ERR!   react-dom@"^0.0.0-experimental-ee8509801-20230117" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react-dom@">=0.14" from react-jvectormap@0.0.16
npm ERR! node_modules/react-jvectormap
npm ERR!   react-jvectormap@"0.0.16" from the root project
```

Is that a way to tell npm that this version of react is OK for peer dependency? I tried to use `overrides` and `legacy-peer-deps=true` in my `.npmrc` but got the same error.

Node version v16.19.0, npm version 8.19.3

Answer (score 0):

Finally found out correct configuration using [overrides](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json/#overrides):

```
  "overrides": {
    "react": "$react",
    "react-dom": "$react-dom"
  }
```